# Force backbone.js to use JSONP when user is using IE9<

Tags: backbone.js

Is there away I could make backbone.js use JSONP when it detects that the client is using IE? But when they are using, say FF or chrome, default to json?

Is there a way to globally change on fetches to JSONP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you would have to find out which browser the client is currently using, there are different ways to do this, I found [this script from quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html) to be useful.
Then you could globally or on model/collection-level override your sync method in Backbone, passing in `{dataType: "jsonp"}` in case of IE in the options hash.

For example:

```
Backbone._sync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function( method, model, options ) {

    if (BrowserDetect.browser === "MSIE" && BrowserDetect.version < 9) {
       options.dataType = "jsonp";
    } 
    return Backbone._sync( method, model, options );
};
```